# How can I group arrays in a one big array in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, array-merge

I have data here:

```
Array
(
    [3] => Array
    (
        [SiteID] => 3
        [Balance] => 94000.99
        [MinBalance] => 100000.00
        [MaxBalance] => 500000.00
        [OwnerAID] => 17
        [GroupID] => 1
        [Deposit] => 459000
        [Redemption] => 703576
        [Reload] => 169100
    )

    [2] => Array
    (
        [SiteID] => 2
        [Balance] => 19000.00
        [MinBalance] => 100000.00
        [MaxBalance] => 1000000.00
        [OwnerAID] => 83
        [GroupID] => 1
        [Deposit] => 1500
        [Redemption] => 1000
        [Reload] => 1000
    )

    [139] => Array
    (
        [SiteID] => 139
        [Balance] => 855100.00
        [MinBalance] => 100000.00
        [MaxBalance] => 1000000.00
        [OwnerAID] => 23
        [GroupID] => 1
        [Deposit] => 0  
        [Redemption] => 0 
        [Reload] => 0 
    )
)
```

I need to group this arrays in to two groups: First group - all OwnerAID owning one SiteID and the Second group all OwnerAID owning more than one SiteID. Is it possible to make it? The result should be shown like this:

here's the group of OwnerAID owning one SiteID in a one big array:

```
Array
(
    [17] => Array
    (
        [Sites] => Array 
        (
            [0] => Array
            (
                [SiteID] => 3 
                [Balance] => 94000.99  
                [MinBalance] => 100000.00   
                [MaxBalance] => 500000.00  
                [OwnerAID] => 17  
                [GroupID] => 1 
                [Deposit] => 459000  
                [Redemption] => 703576 
                [Reload] => 169100 
            )
        )
    )    
}
```

while here, OwnerAID owning more than one SiteID in another one big array:

```
Array
 (
    [83] => Array
    (
        [Sites] => Array 
        (
        [0] => Array
        (
            [SiteID] => 2
            [Balance] => 19000.00
            [MinBalance] => 100000.00
            [MaxBalance] => 1000000.00
            [OwnerAID] => 83
            [GroupID] => 1
            [Deposit] => 1500
            [Redemption] => 1000
            [Reload] => 1000
        ) 
        [1] => Array
        (
            [SiteID] => 149
            [Balance] => 150000.00
            [MinBalance] => 100000.00
            [MaxBalance] => 250000.00
            [OwnerAID] => 83
            [GroupID] => 1
            [Deposit] => 0
            [Redemption] => 0
            [Reload] => 0
        )
    )
)
```

Someone suggest me this code but I already modified it, I do some research to modify this code. Please help me to accomplish this kind of result. Please be patient in answering my question, I'm just a beginner in a world of programming in PHP.here's the code:

```
public function groupIndividualAndAggregateSites() 
{
    $owners = array();
    foreach($this->combined as $key => $value) {
        $owner_id = $value['OwnerAID'];
        $site_id = $value['SiteID'];
        if (array_key_exists($owner_id,$owners)) {
            // He has one or more sites already?
            if(is_array($owners[$owner_id])) {
                array_push($owners[$owner_id],$site_id);
            } else {
                // User already has one site.  
                // Make an array instead and add old and new siteID
                $old_site_id = $owners[$site_id];
                $owners[$owner_id] = array_merge((array)$value, array($old_site_id));
            }
        } else {
            $owners[$owner_id] = array($value,'Sites'=> array($site_id));
        }
    }
    print_r($owners); 
}
```

Please help me, and Thank you in advance. I hope someone could help me to come up with this kind of result. Please guide me in proper way.

Comment: Do you want to group arrays with the same `OwnerAID`?

Comment: No, I need to group the OwnerAID in to two big array, the first one is the OwnerAID having one SiteID and the second one is OwnerAID having more than one SiteID. Please review my question please. Thanks.

Comment: If you don't need 3d array with additional array `[Sites]`, i guess code in my answer will help. if you need it i'll try to rewrite it.

Comment: Hi loler, if you dont mind, can you modify your code.Please.Thank you.

Comment: can you give it a try until i modify it?

Comment: i modified it, plz give it a try.

Comment: yes, I've tried it. Sure, I'll try it again. Thanks you so much.

Comment: Modified. Returns exactly what you want. Included Array declaration for testing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This returns exactly what you want.

```
    <?php

//Array declaration
    $arr = Array
    (
        3 => Array
        (
            "SiteID" => 3,
            "Balance" => 94000,
            "MinBalance" => 100000.00,
            "MaxBalance" => 500000.00,
            "OwnerAID" => 17,
            "GroupID" => 1,
            "Deposit" => 459000,
            "Redemption" => 703576,
            "Reload" => 169100,
        ),

        2 => Array
        (
            "SiteID" => 2,
            "Balance" => 19000.00,
            "MinBalance" => 100000.00,
            "MaxBalance" => 1000000.00,
            "OwnerAID" => 83,
            "GroupID" => 1,
            "Deposit" => 1500,
            "Redemption" => 1000,
            "Reload" => 1000,
        ),

        139 => Array
        (
            "SiteID" => 139,
            "Balance" => 855100.00,
            "MinBalance" => 100000.00,
            "MaxBalance" => 1000000.00,
            "OwnerAID" => 83,
            "GroupID" => 1,
            "Deposit" => 0,
            "Redemption" => 0 ,
            "Reload" => 0 
        ),
      );


//End of declaration;
//Too lazy for other comments, sorry xD


    foreach ($arr as $key => $value) {
        $Newarr[$value["OwnerAID"]][] = $value; 
    }
    foreach ($Newarr as $key => $value) {
        foreach ($value as $key2 => $value2) {          
        if (count($value) == 1)
            $arrOneSite[$value2["OwnerAID"]]["Sites"][] = $value2;
            else    
                $arrMoreThenOneSite[$value2["OwnerAID"]]["Sites"][] = $value2;
        }
    }

    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($arrOneSite);
    print_r($arrMoreThenOneSite);
    ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

sorry,i found reading the code is a little difficult,so i write one for you.

```
$new_array=array();
foreach($old_array as $site)
{
    $siteList=array();
    if(isset($new_array[$site['OwnerAID']]['Sites']))
        $siteList=$new_array[$site['OwnerAID']]['Sites'];
    $new_array=array_merge($new_array,array($site['OwnerAID']=>array_merge($siteList,$site['SiteID']=>array('Sites'=>array(
                                                 'SiteID'=>$site['SiteID'],
                                                 'Balance'=>$site['Balance'],
                                                 'MinBalance'=>$site['MinBalance'],
                                                 'MaxBalance'=>$site['MaxBalance'],
                                                 'OwnerAID'=>$site['OwnerAID'],
                                                 'GroupID'=>$site['GroupID'],
                                                 'Deposit'=>$site['Deposit'],
                                                 'Redemption'=>$site['Redemption'],
                                                 'Reload'=>$site['Reload'],
                                                 )))));
}
```

Comment: Hi Wenhuang Lin, there something wrong with the $new_array, it occurs error, kindly review the code. Please. Thank you so much.

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_DOUBLE_ARROW, Please help me to debug. Thank you so much.

Comment: @Wenhuang Lin,It starts with $new_array, here's the error:Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_DOUBLE_ARROW in /var/www/joy/AutoTopup/config.php on line 314 Call Stack: 0.0000 315440 1. {main}() /var/www/joy/AutoTopup/index.php:0